# How may I prove that $2^{\frac{1}{3}}+3^\frac{1}{2}$ is not a rational number?

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory

How may I prove that 
$$2^{\frac{1}{3}}+3^\frac{1}{2}$$
is not a rational number?

Thank for any help.
Jean

Comment: Have you tried raising it to a $6$th power?

Comment: Are you familiar with the rational root theorem?

Comment: It depends on which knowledge you may use. Do you need algebraic arguments (like fields?)

Comment: Using field theory, if $\alpha=2^{1/3}+3^{1/2}$ were rational then $\Bbb Q(2^{1/3})=\Bbb Q(\alpha-2^{1/3})=\Bbb Q(3^{1/2})$ would have degree three *and* two over $\Bbb Q$, which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks..my only knowledge is that sqrt(2) is not a rational number. I think I can deal with the proof that sqrt(3) is not rational.

Answer (score 10):

Suppose that $2^{1/3}+3^{1/2}=r$, where $r$ is rational. Then $2^{1/3}=r-3^{1/2}$. Cubing both sides, we get
$$2=r^3-3r^23^{1/2}+9r-(3)3^{1/2}.$$
Rearrange. We get 
$$(3r^2+3)3^{1/2}=r^3+9r-2.$$
This is impossible, by the irrationality of $3^{1/2}$, which you undoubtedly know how to handle.

Comment: Still you have to use 3^1/2 is irrational. Anon's field argument doesn't (directly)

Comment: Does your argument rely on proving that multiplying a rational and a irrational is an irrational?

Comment: @Bernd: Certainly. I was trying to give a proof that uses little machinery.

Comment: @Pinocchio: I had in mind the same thing, but in the form $3^{1/2}=\frac{r^3+9r-2}{3(r^2+1)}$, the ratio of rationals is rational.

Comment: @Pinocchio: The argument is: It can't be that one side of an equation is rational, the other isn't

Answer (score 1):

You can verify that $2^{1/3}+3^{1/2}$ is a root of the polynomial
$$
p(x) = x^6-9 x^4-4 x^3+27 x^2-36 x-23;
$$
but the only possible rational roots of $p(x)$ are $\pm1$ and $\pm23$.

(While knowing where $p(x)$ comes from isn't necessary for executing the above proof, it comes from knowing that the minimal polynomial of $2^{1/3}+3^{1/2}$ equals
\begin{multline*}
(x-2^{1/3}-3^{1/2})(x-2^{1/3}e^{2\pi i/3}-3^{1/2})(x-2^{1/3}e^{-2\pi i/3}-3^{1/2}) \\
{}\times (x-2^{1/3}+3^{1/2})(x-2^{1/3}e^{2\pi i/3}+3^{1/2})(x-2^{1/3}e^{-2\pi i/3}+3^{1/2}),
\end{multline*}
which when expanded out equals $p(x)$.)